# Getting jzebra to print using sample files on ESC/P printer

Tags: epson

I need some assistance trying to execute a demo print from jzebra to an ESC/P printer (epson tm88iv). I don't believe I am using the correct methods, but am wondering if anyone has sample text/data to use for the sample2.html file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will likely need to use esc/p formatted commands.  Hit up the jzebra mailing list jzebra-users@googlegroups.com. Or download the proper programmers guide from the epson website.